# hector_slam with odometry?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My data is from a big tunnel, about 700m long, and I want to do some mapping.
The problem is, that each scan looks nearly the same, with no big changes and the scanmatcher without odometry has some problems...
The robot thinks he is always standing at the same position instead of driving forwards.

Soon as I am in the tunnel, scanmatcher seems to overrule the odometry data and the robot is not moving any farther.
Is it possible to change that or somehow deactivate scanmatching?

`<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="scanmatcher_odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom map
100"/> 
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="scanmatcher_baselink_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 scanmatcher_frame base_link 100"/>

 <include file="$(find velodyne_mapping)/launch/assembler_to_2d_laser.launch"/>  

 <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">


<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
<param name="output_timing" value="false"/>

<param name="scan_topic" value="scan"/>

# Map size / start point 
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.1"/>
<param name="map_size" value="4096"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />

# Map update parameters 
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />


 </node>

 </launch>`

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64217/hector_slam-with-odometry?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I should probably update the documentation to state this more clearly: The odom frame is used in hector_mapping mainly to provide the same interface as gmapping does. Internally, odometry is completely ignored for mapping currently and just used to be able to publish the map->odom transform correctly. This is advantageous if you can't rely on odometry, but obviously a disadvantage in this tunnel scenario. Support for odometry could be added, but that will require some effort (if someone wants to look at it :) ).

That being said, I'm pretty sure I know which robot was used for this dataset and with the ton of sensors you strapped onto it there are a lot of other approaches you could try. The Velodyne data plus some registration approach (for example [ethzasl_icp_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapping)) would be my first try.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-06-05**:
Thank you! That clears all up. Will have a look at it.